# Вот и сейчас (?) ты затихла... Пунктуация

Tags: пунктуация, грамотная-речь, авторская-пунктуация

> Да, я тебя и всех вас воспринимаю только как врагов, желающих меня
> разрушить (и мою семью - тоже). Только по этой причине я боялся
> потерять контроль, снять руку с пульса. Вот и сейчас (?) ты затихла, а
> у меня тревога, что вы готовите какую-то гадость. Надеюсь, что это не
> так!

Перед "ты" нужно что-то поставить. Что? Двоеточие? Тире? Многоточие? Запятую? Если написать без знаков препинания, то получится, что она и раньше затихала. Но не об этом речь. Смысл - другой!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Вот и сейчас: ты затихла, а у меня тревога, что вы готовите какую-то гадость.**

["Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации", § 161](http://new.gramota.ru/biblio/readingroom/rules/157-dvoe):

> Двоеточие ставится после предложения, за которым следует одно или
> несколько предложений, не соединенных с первым посредством cоюзов и
> заключающих в себе <...> разъяснение или раскрытие содержания того, о
> чем говорится в первом предложении, например:
>
> *Я не ошибся: старик не отказался от предлагаемого стакана* (Пушкин).

Comment: А многоточие или запятую поставить можно?

Comment: @МоняЛевински многоточие можно, запятую — сомневаюсь (хотя "вот и сейчас", вероятно, можно рассматривать как вводное сочетание). Можно ничего не ставить, но тогда будет, как вы и сами заметили, другой смысл.

Comment: @МоняЛевински Тире можно поставить, если не хотите останавливаться и делать длительную паузу. Здесь темп речь какой-то "нервный",  тревожный, поэтому тире мне больше нравится.  По правилам это возможно.  А вот запятой будет недостаточно, потому что пауза явно требуется и нужны более сильные знаки (двоеточие или тире).

Comment: Благодарю. Получается, поставить можно всё! Nektoid сказал, что "вот и сейчас", вероятно, можно рассматривать как вводное сочетание, тогда, возможно, запятую и можно поставить. А можно ли рассматривать "вот и сейчас" как вводное сочетание?

Comment: @Sharon вы ж сами писали: двоеточие при раскрытии информации, тире при присоединении. Здесь явное раскрытие.

Comment: Ну да, это верно. Но тире может заменять двоеточие, об этом говорится у Розенталя. http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=185#pp1855. Вариативны двоеточие и тире в бессоюзных сложных предложениях с пояснительными отношениями. Пункт 5.

Comment: @Sharon это да, но, по моим наблюдениям, двоеточие хорошо заменяется тире, когда последнее присоединяет заключительную часть предложения. Таким образом пояснение получает дополнительный оттенок — присоединения. А тут начало предложения... Выглядит, как по мне, неуместно. Хоть формально и допустимо.

Comment: Вам нужно войти в роль. Представьте себя на месте этого человека. Он взволнован, говорит быстро, на секунду прислушивается к себе и потом продолжает речь.  Что правила!  Нам нужна художественность и индивидуальность эпизода, чтобы Станиславский похвалил :)) А правила разрешают замену, пользуйтесь этой свободой.

Comment: @Sharon не верю! (с).

Comment: Ну тогда ставьте свое двоеточие...  Но все-таки подумайте, ведь там даже запятую хотели поставить. А  это почти присоединительное (распространительное) тире. пауза чуть больше, чем у запятой.

Comment: @Sharon а где прописана сравнительная длина пауз, обозначаемых тире, двоеточием, запятой?

Comment: Найдите в Сети  такую книгу: Г. И. Кустова «Синтаксис современного русского языка». Курс лекций.   Издание не позднее 2013 года. Это грамматика, но  в БСП интонация является основным средством связи, поэтому там прописано и движение тона, и паузы для разных знаков.
У меня был вроде бесплатный адрес (кажется 2018 года), но я его потеряла, а найти не могу.  А так ее не дают читать, нужно покупать. У меня бумажный вариант 2013 года, он более полный, чем 2005 год, который можно найти.

Comment: @Sharon спасибо, поищу и почитаю, как только закончу с розенталевским справочником. 2013 года на Литрес есть, но там только в пдф и даже скачать нельзя будет после покупки. Попробую найти без таких ограничений.